# Making text appear through myFunction

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got this code:

```js
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
}
```

```css
body,
hmtl {
  background- color: black;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.bar1,
.bar2,
.bar3 {
  width: 39px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}

.change .bar1 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  transform: rotate(-345deg) translate(-9px, 6px);
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  top: -100px;
  width: 200px;
}

.change .bar2 {
  opacity: 6;
  transform: rotate(3000deg);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  left: 200px;
  background- color: green;
  top: -200px;
}

.change .bar3 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-8px, -8px);
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  left: 100px;
  bottom: 200px;
}
```

```html
<a id="mobile-nav" href="#">
  <div class="container" onclick="myFunction(this)">
    <div class="bar1"></div>
    <div class="bar2"></div>
    <div class="bar3"></div>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'd like to make text appear when i click it, but not sure how.

I have this:

```js
function changeText(id) {
  id.innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <h1 onclick="changeText(this)">Click on this text!
  </h1>
</body>
</html>
```

But not sure how to combine it with `my Function` and want it to go from no text to `Hello`. Is it just a matter of adding

```
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

between existing script tags?

At the moment shapes appear, but how can i get a word to appear, perhaps several, through `myFunction`? Is it even possible to morph a shape into a word?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you want both actions to happen when you click on the same element? Use `onclick="myFunction(this); changeText(this);"`

Comment: Or `myFunction` can call `changeText(x)`

Comment: As it is i have three blobs which morph into different shapes. So 1 is is possible, when i click those blobs, to make a word appear that wasn't there before and if so how please? 2. Is it possible to to get one of the shapes to morph into a word? Thanks.

Comment: 1. Assigning to `innerHTML` or `innerText` will make text appear. I don't know how to make the text participate in the transition.

Comment: I don't even see anything to click on in the first snippet.

Comment: @Barmar well it works and the code is all there. Maybe there's some malfunctioning in the snippet...

Comment: @Barmar Great. If assigning this `function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Hello";`makes text appear. How can i select/ adjust text with css? Thanks 
}

Comment: Sorry, fancy CSS tricks are not my area of expertise

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can call `changeText()` from `myFunctio()`

```
function myFunction(x) {
  x.classList.toggle('change');
  changeText(x);
}
function changeText(id) {
    id.innerHTML = "Hello";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do by just replace your code with this:

`

```
<h1  onclick="changeText()">Click on this text!</h1>
    <script>
        function changeText() {
            event.target.innerHTML = "Hello";
        }
    </script>
```

`

Comment: `this` is the event target.

Answer (score -1):

```
<h1 onclick="changeText()" id="myText">Click on this text! </h1>
 <script>
    function changeText() {
       document.getElementById("myText").innerHTML = "Hello";
    }
 </script>
```

Comment: Why is it better to hard-code the ID than pass the element as a parameter?

Comment: You're more knowledgeable than me and I'm lost now. As much layman's as you can please :-) I just want to have a word appear when i click on it...

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.